# Factor a grammar

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, context-free

Consider the context free grammar:

$\qquad \begin{align}
    \mathrm{bill} &\to \mathrm{items}\ \mathrm{total}\ \mathrm{vat} \\
    \mathrm{items} &\to \mathrm{item} \mid \mathrm{item}\ \mathrm{items} \\
    \mathrm{item} &\to name\ \mathrm{price} \mid name\ \mathrm{quantity}\ \mathrm{price} \\
    \mathrm{quantity} &\to integer \\
    \mathrm{price} &\to integer \\
    \mathrm{total} &\to integer \mid TOTAL\ \mathrm{price}  \\
    \mathrm{vat} &\to VAT\ \mathrm{price}  
\end{align}$

How do I factor the grammar?

This was asked in a past exam, and I don't know how to get started.

Also, if you have any links that could help me understand this more it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean [left-factoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_factoring)? In that case, see [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/left-recursion-and-left-factoring-which-one-goes-first) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

To factor a grammar you need to check the alternatives of productions (those separated by `|`) whether they have some common symbols in sequence. For example, whether they have a common prefix (that is, whether they start with the same symbol). Join together as many subsequet common symbols (common factors) as you can, and put the rest into parentheses. For example, look at the productions for `item`:

```
item --> NAME price | NAME quantity price
```

You can rewrite all alternatives one below the other to better see the common prefix:

```
item --> NAME price
item --> NAME quantity price
```

Now you can see that they both start with `NAME`, and they both end with `price`. The only difference is the presence of the middle term `quantity`, which seems to be optional:

```
item --> NAME () price
item --> NAME (quantity) price
```

So you can rewrite it like this, making a new production for the contents of the parenthesis:

```
item --> NAME optionalQuantity price
```

and the new symbol `optionalQuantity` you've just introduced can be equal to what? The `quantity` or just nothing. So you write it down this way:

```
optionalQuantity --> quantity
optionalQuantity -->
```

As you can see, the last production for `optionalQuantity` is empty. This form is sometimes called *erasure*, because it can "erase" its own symbol from other productions (could be replaced by nothing at all). If you're allowed to use EBNF, you can write all the above three productions as such:

```
item --> NAME quantity? price
```

The question mark after `quantity` means that it could be omitted (it's optional). Then you don't need a separate productions for `optionalQuantity`.

You can apply the same technique for `items` production:

```
items --> item | item items
```

When you rewrite the alternatives separately, you can see, they both start with `item`, and then there's an optional `items` again:

```
items --> item
items --> item items
```

or with parentheses around symbols which are not common:

```
items --> item ()
items --> item (items)
```

so in EBNF you could write it just like:

```
items --> item items?
```

or in plain context-free grammar as:

```
items    --> item optItems
optItems --> items
optItems -->
```

And then the syntax is factored. But notice what the above syntax really says: It says that `items` is just one `item`, which optionally could be followed by more items. In EBNF you could express it shorter like this:

```
items --> item item*
```

where star after `item` means that it could be repeated zero or more times. But it could be rewritten even further, because one followed by zero or more is the same as one or more. So you can express it more shortly as:

```
items --> item+
```

where `+` means "one or more".

Comment: Does this always work? That is, please add a reference for the general method. Also, you might want to use LaTeX syntax instead of code blocks. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) to get you started. Otherwise, nice answer!