# Correct name for a recursive descent parser that uses loops to handle left recursion?

Tags: reference-request, formal-grammars, recursion, parsers, left-recursion

This grammar is left recursive:

```
Expression  ::= AdditionExpression

AdditionExpression  ::=
    MultiplicationExpression
        | AdditionExpression '+' MultiplicationExpression
        | AdditionExpression '-' MultiplicationExpression

MultiplicationExpression    ::=
    Term
        | MultiplicationExpression '*' Term
        | MultiplicationExpression '/' Term

Term    ::=
    Number
        | '(' AdditionExpression ')'

Number  ::=
    [+-]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?
```

So in theory, recursive descent won't work. But by exploiting the properties of the grammar that each left-recursive rule corresponds to a specific precedence level, and that lookahead of a single token is enough to choose the correct production, the left-recursive rules can be individually parsed with while loops.

For example, to parse the AdditionExpression non-terminal, this pseudocode suffices:

```
function parse_addition_expression() {
    num = parse_multiplication_expression()
    while (has_token()) {
        get_token()
        if (current_token == PLUS)
            num += parse_multiplication_expression()
        else if (current_token == MINUS)
            num -= parse_multiplication_expression()
        else {
            unget_token()
            return num
        }
    }
    return num
}
```

What is the correct name for this type of parser? This informative article only refers to it as the "Classic Solution": https://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/Misc/exp_parsing.htm

There must be a proper name for this type of parser.

Comment: For me it is not a kind of parser, it is just the application of left recursion removal combined with a recursive descent parser. See  [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2720/584) for a technique to remove left recursion.

Comment: I think you might be correct. It does resemble a run-time equivalent of the left-recursion removal algorithm.

Comment: Please don't use the 'answer' box to post comments or other remarks.  If you [create an account](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/why-register), you'll retain access and be able to accept the answer that helped you most.  If you entered an email and lost access, [you can recover access](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/reset-password).  If you didn't enter an email address and don't have access to the browser/cookies you used to post the question, you're probably out of luck. No one else can accept the answer for you -- not even moderators.

Answer (score 11):

It is just an LL(1) parser implemented with recursive descent.

Starts with:

```
AdditionExpression  ::=
    MultiplicationExpression
        | AdditionExpression '+' MultiplicationExpression
        | AdditionExpression '-' MultiplicationExpression
```

apply [left-recursion removal](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2720/584) to get an LL(1) grammar:

```
AdditionExpression  ::= 
    MultiplicationExpression AdditionExpressionTail

AdditionExpressionTail ::=
        | '+' MultiplicationExpression AdditionExpressionTail
        | '-' MultiplicationExpression AdditionExpressionTail
```

write the corresponding functions:

```
function parse_AdditionExpression() {
    parse_MultiplicationExpression()
    parse_AdditionExpressionTail()
}

function parse_AdditionExpressionTail() {
    if (has_token()) {
        get_token()
        if (current_token == PLUS) {
            parse_MultiplicationExpression()
            parse_AdditionExpressionTail()
        } else if (current_token == MINUS) {
            parse_MultiplicationExpression()
            parse_AdditionExpressionTail()
        } else {
            unget_token()
        }
    }
}
```

remove tail recursion:

```
function parse_AdditionExpressionTail() {
    while (has_token()) {
        get_token()
        if (current_token == PLUS)
            parse_MultiplicationExpression()
        else if (current_token == MINUS)
            parse_MultiplicationExpression()
        else {
            unget_token()
            return
        }
    }
}
```

inline:

```
function parse_AdditionExpression() {
    parse_MultiplicationExpression()
    while (has_token()) {
        get_token()
        if (current_token == PLUS)
            parse_MultiplicationExpression()
        else if (current_token == MINUS)
            parse_MultiplicationExpression()
        else {
            unget_token()
            return
        }
    }
}
```

and you have just to add the semantic processing to get your function.

Answer (score 5):

You want to look into [LL($k$) parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser). The Wikipedia article is mostly useless, but it's basically recursive descent with $k$ symbols lookahead.

There is also LL($*$) which permits unbounded lookahead.

See [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/48/98) for a comprehensive overview on how powerful this class of parsers is.

Comment: I don't see how this is related. The code does not use more than one symbol of look-ahead.

Comment: @AProgrammer So it's an LL(1) parser, or very closely related.

Comment: It's an LL(1) parser.  I expanded my comment into an answer.

Comment: @AProgrammer I don't see how a second answer was needed. LL(1) is LL(k) for k=1 (isn't that obvious?). But well.

Comment: LL(k) is not enough. For left recursion the parser might need arbitrarily big lookahead.